# Symbol for obliqueness.

Tags: notation

Is there a universally recognised symbol for "is oblique to"? After all, there is $\parallel$ for "is parallel to" and $\perp$ for "is perpendicular/orthogonal to". Using $\require{cancel}\cancel\parallel$ is ugly and cumbersome, in addition to being somewhat ambiguous. `\oblique` is not defined in plain TeX, but maybe it bears another name(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallelism and orthogonality represent certain special angle relationships between two lines ($0^\circ$ and $90^\circ$) respectively, which can be applied to infer other facts about diagrams containing those lines.
By contrast, there's no particular angle measure related to having an oblique intersection, and no special theorems related to obliqueness that I know of in [Euclidean geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry) that aren't just formed by [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) from known facts about lines being parallel or perpendicular.
I think the field would be wide-open for someone to define their own symbol for obliqueness, but I also think it wouldn't see widespread use, due to lack of suitable/necessary contexts.